# unicodecsv.DictReader not working with io.StringIO (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, csv, utf-8, stringio

I was trying to use csv.DictReader to parse UTF-8 data with special characters but I was getting the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I read online and found out that Python 2.7's csv library doesn't handle Unicode. I looked for an alternative library and found `unicodecsv`.

I replaced csv with unicodecsv but I get the same error. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from io import StringIO
from unicodecsv import DictReader, Dialect, QUOTE_MINIMAL

data = (
    'first_name,last_name,email\r'
    'Elmer,Fudd,elmer@looneytunes.com\r'
    'Jo\xc3\xa3o Ant\xc3\xb4nio,Ara\xc3\xbajo,joaoantonio@araujo.com\r'
)

unicode_data = StringIO(unicode(data, 'utf-8-sig'), newline=None)

class CustomDialect(Dialect):
    delimiter = ','
    doublequote = True
    escapechar = '\\'
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quotechar = '"'
    quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
    skipinitialspace = True

rows = DictReader(unicode_data, dialect=CustomDialect)

for row in rows:
    print row
```

If I replace StringIO with BytesIO, the encoding works but I can't send the `newlines` argument anymore and then I get:

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Does anybody have any idea how I could solve this? Shouldn't unicodecsv be handling StringIO? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv/issues/42) in the unicodecsv github page and it turns out (a bit counterintuitively imo) that the unicodecsv reader expects a bytestring and not a unicode object.

After taking some time to make this whole thing with Unicode and encodings clearer in my head, it turns out I didn't really need unicodecsv in the first place. After all, the initial problem is that `io.StringIO`, when iterated with `.next()`, was returning unicode objects to the csv.DictReader, which expected bytestrings. So if unicodecsv also expects bytestrings it obviously can't solve the problem.

My solution was changing the file-like object I was passing to the csv.DictReader so that it returned properly encoded bytestrings instead of unicode objects:

```
class UTF8EncodedStringIO(StringIO):
    def next(self):
        return super(UTF8EncodedStringIO, self).next().encode('utf-8')

udata = UTF8EncodedStringIO(unicode(data, 'utf-8-sig'), newline=None)
```

By writing this simple wrapper around StringIO instead of using BytesIO I could solve the encoding problems and profit from the `newline` argument. There's a bit of decoding/encoding overhead but I was out of alternatives. If somebody has a better suggestion, feel free to share.